# Disnake. Бот не запускается на хостинге

Tags: python

Всем привет, возникла проблема. Бот запускается на локальном компьютере, закинул его на хостинг, и тут проблема: выдает следующую ошибку:

```
File "/home/FeeFort/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('162.159.138.232', 443)]
```

Возможно, проблема в самом хостинге, но может есть способ, как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: А на каком хостинге бот?